# Distinct or Unique values from CSV using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Today, I was asked by a friend who uses macros and Excel spreadsheets if there was a way to convert a csv integer string to csv with distinct values. Being from modern era of linq and fancy huha, I thought it would be straight forward, but I spent a good hour to come up with my own solution after Google and SO not turning up. I'd like to know if there's a better solution to it. Here is the input:
"1,45,2,4,5,2,3,5"
Expected output:
"1,45,2,4,5,3"

I'll post my solution soon, but I am hoping to hear a better SO solution.

Comment: Post your solution first? - if I was to do this I would just split the commas into an array loop through that array and have a function that checks if the number exists already in a second array - if it does I wouldnt add it otherwise i would

Comment: @JamesCooke, you're right, I should've waited until I got on a computer to post my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a dictionary as a quick and easy way to do this. Add values to dictionary using overwrite syntax to handle duplicates. Then use `.Keys` to generate an array which you can return as a string by using `Join` with delimiter `","`.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Test()
    Dim inputValue As String, outputValue As String, arr() As String, i As Long, dict As Object
    inputValue = "1,45,2,4,5,2,3,5"
    arr = Split(inputValue, ",")
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        dict(arr(i)) = vbNullString
    Next
    outputValue = Join(dict.keys, ",")
    Debug.Print outputValue
End Sub
```

Comment: Marked this as answer for it's simplicity.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this as a basis for what you want to do - there are some steps to help demonstrate what I said in my comment - perhaps instead of building a collection and then converting it into an array which is joined in the msgbox you could write it to a cell - or do whatever you want with it downstream. This would reduce the need for the collectionToArray function.

Alternatively you could do this with arrays, but i find collections to be neater.

```
Public Sub GetDistinctCommaSeparated()

Dim values As String
Dim valuesArr() As String
Dim DistinctCol As New Collection

' Get an array from the comma separated field
values = Range("A1").Value
valuesArr = Split(values, ",")

' get a distinct collection
Set DistinctCol = MakeCommaArrayDistinct(valuesArr)

' convert to array - and join (demonstration purposes)
MsgBox Join(CollectionToArray(DistinctCol), ",")


End Sub

Private Function MakeCommaArrayDistinct(valuesArr() As String) As Collection

Dim output As New Collection

 ' Loop through your array and push items to a secondary collection only if they are not already there
 For Each x In valuesArr
        If IsInCollection(CStr(x), output) <> True Then
          output.Add CStr(x)
        End If
    Next x

Set MakeCommaArrayDistinct = output

End Function

' Checks if the current item exists within the collection
Public Function IsInCollection(stringToBeFound As String, col As Collection) As Boolean

    Dim x As Variant

    ' Empty Collection
    If col.Count = 0 Then
        IsInCollection = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Loop and Check
    For Each x In col
        If CStr(x) = stringToBeFound Then
            IsInCollection = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next x

End Function

' Used to convert the collection to an array to easily display in the msgbox - Demonstration only
Public Function CollectionToArray(myCol As Collection) As Variant

    Dim result  As Variant
    Dim cnt     As Long

    ReDim result(myCol.Count - 1)

    For cnt = 0 To myCol.Count - 1
        result(cnt) = myCol(cnt + 1)
    Next cnt

    CollectionToArray = result

End Function
```

output;

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution I came up with

```
Function GetUnique(notUnique As String) As String

    ar = Split(notUnique, ",")
    Dim result As String
    Dim retVal As New Collection

    For Each a In ar
     If HasKey(retVal, a) Then
      ' do nothomg
     Else
      retVal.Add a, a
     End If
    Next
    result = ""
    For Each r In retVal
     result = result + r + ","
    Next

    GetUnique = Mid(result, 1, Len(result) - 1)

End Function

Function HasKey(coll As Collection, strKey) As Boolean
    Dim var As Variant
    On Error Resume Next
    var = coll(strKey)
    HasKey = (Err.Number = 0)
    Err.Clear
End Function
```